# Physics2D.CircleCast works strange

Tags: unity, 2d, raycasting

I'm creating a 2D game and spawn my enemies with `Collider 2D` and `Rigidbody2D`, and my hero is attacking them, but he casts his attacking ray in strange directions (but mostly if works ok for moving enemies), but it doesn't see static enemies at all! Like I literally can't kill them when I'm in front of them. I guess the problem is in the direction Vector, but I have no idea what I should change

```
Collider2D enemy= Physics2D.CircleCast(this.transform.position, 2, new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")), 3).collider;
 if (enemy.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            {
                soundSource2.PlayOneShot(slice);
                if (enemy.GetComponent<MoveToWayPoints>() != null) // the check of moving enemy
                    enemy.GetComponent<MoveToWayPoints>().hp.GetComponent<HP>().Dmg(10, 1);
                if (enemy.GetComponent<ShamanScript>() != null) // the check of static shaman enemy
                {
                    enemy.GetComponent<ShamanScript>().hp.GetComponent<HP>().Dmg(10, 1);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you are continuing to hold the analog stick (or WASD keys) in the direction of the static enemy over the whole time interval in which this code should run? (ie. you don't walk up to the static enemy, release the stick/WASD keys to stop, *then* attack?) If so, can you edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example? We'll need to see how the working and non-working enemies as well as your player object are set up in the hierarchy and inspector, so we can reproduce the same situation in a new, empty project.

Comment: Can you explain `MoveToWayPoint` and `ShamanScript`? Also, is that `hp` acts the same in both of the components?

Comment: @DMGregory yes, I'm using WASD and trying to hit from all sides. And I forget to say, moving enemies are attackable, but when they are lose their speed from code, they're not see my attacks

Comment: @ariankeshvari `MoveToWayPoint` uped to every spawned enemy. It gives them a point where to go, methods how to give a damage and to stop before it and how to be destroyed. Also there is hp object to every enemy, which decreases. `ShamanScript` is a script for static enemy shaman, which slow down my hero. It also has hp component.

Comment: So what's the difference between the hp components on the two scripts? I would say create a hp script to use for every enemy in the game, it's really time-saving. Also, try using `TryGetComponent`  instead of null check

Comment: @ariankeshvari this is the main misunderstanding from me. I use the same samples for both of enemy type

Comment: what about the tag on static enemies? Is it set to `Enemy` like the moving ones? and you said it works "mostly" for the moving enemies so what are the exceptions?

Comment: @ariankeshvari yes, I use tags. Just i don't know how to explain. Like enemy is moving and attacks give damage them. Mostly, but sometimes it works in another side, when I hit. And if enemy is get static after moving or static from the start like shaman, I'm trying to hit like 30 seconds and maybe only after this it will work, but no guarantee

Comment: there are three other things that may cause the problem:

1- it may be better to use `Input.GetAxis()` because the number can vary between -1 and 1.

-2- how are you moving the enemies? I've found out that `rigidbody.MovePosition` is the only thing that works for me

-3- I'm more confident that this one is the cause of your problem: use `Physics2D.CircleCastAll` and check all of the objects that are in contact with it